# How to change the cursor of Textfield with type=date in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

I would like to change my text field cursor to the pointer. Please find my code for TextField

```
<TextField inputProps={{ style: { cursor: 'pointer' } }}
              className={classes.textField}
              defaultValue={moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
              id="date"
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
                classes: {
                  root: classes.labelRoot,
                  focused: classes.labelFocused
                }
              }}
              InputProps={{
                classes: {
                  input: classes.textfiledSize
                }
              }}
              onChange={event =>
                handleFieldChange('visitdate', event.target.value)
              }
              type="date"
              value={
                values.visitdate
                  ? moment(values.visitdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                  : ''
              }
              variant="outlined"
            />
```

Here I can change the cursor of input rather than the calendar indicator.

I checked with the below code in style but not working

```
 '&:-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator' : {
        cursor: "pointer"
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this - 
  

  <TextField
              error
              id="standard-error-helper-text"
              label="Error"
              defaultValue="Hello World"
              helperText="Incorrect entry."
              style={{
                cursor: "pointer"
              }}
            />
```

link - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-zzt5d?file=/demo.js

Comment: I have implemented the same for textbox and I need it for the calendar indicator